# Are there limits to how deep nesting of header inclusion can go?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, limit, header-files, nested

I can't find anything on MSDN or elsewhere, but are there hard-coded limits to how deep nesting of header inclusion can go? Example:

```
// H1.h
// guards etc.
#include "H2.h"

// H2.h
// guards etc.
#include "H3.h"

//...

// HN.h <---- how large can N get??
```

I wonder if there is anything in the Standard about this. If the answer is implementation defined, then I'm primarily interested in the Visual Studio toolchain.

Comment: It's easy to figure out. Just have a file include itself, and see when it errors. You can use `#warning` to force a header to print something out, if the error message doesn't have a depth. Clang stops at 200, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard also says something about it (in the part about implementation quantities, annex B):

> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below
>   or others. The bracketed number following each quantity is recommended
>   as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are only
>   guidelines and do not determine compliance.
>
> ...
>
> - Nesting levels for #include files [256].

Note that this is only a recommended minimum, so a compiler may not support that many inclusions (but most compilers do, as shown in other answers).

Comment: +1 for the Standard quote and accepted. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a header file that includes itself and compiled it with MSVS 2010. That gave the error message:

```
fatal error C1014: too many include files : depth = 1024
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes: 200. At least for my version of gcc.

It can be easily tested:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0

touch "test$i.c"

while gcc -c "test$i.c"; do
  j="$[ $i + 1 ]"
  echo "#include \"test$i.c\"" > "test$j.c"
  i="$j"
  echo "$j" | grep -q "000$" && echo "$j are fine"
done
```

This yields:

```
In file included from test2.c:1:0,
             from test3.c:1,
             from test4.c:1,
             ...
             from test198.c:1,
             from test199.c:1,
             from test200.c:1:
test1.c:1:19: error: #include nested too deeply
```

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN for Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Nesting of include files can continue up to 10 levels.

**UPDATE**:

This "official" limit is probably more of a guideline so that people won't start to stack include files for no reason. I do not believe that there has been a compiler with so restrictive inclusion limits for a couple of decades at least.

For example, according to one of the other answers at least one version of the VS C++ compiler supports about 1024 nesting levels.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: I suspect that this "official" limit is actually more of a guideline so that people won't start to stack include files for no reason. The actual limit is probably a lot higher - although that does not make the VS C++ compiler suck any less...

Comment: " I suspect that this "official" limit is actually more of a guideline so that people won't start to stack include files for no reason" I don't why peoples would do that in their projects without any reasonable reason

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: rampant foolishness?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: the problem is that if you have a layered architecture with several layers, you could easily end up with more than 10 or even 20 levels of inclusion.

Comment: @thkala Exactly, that's the reason I asked: I know that layers should define abstractions (template parameters or pointers to abstract base classes) so that you can eliminate header dependency completely or just put in forward declarations. But with legacy code, it's nice to know what limits there are.