# Header Inclusion Depth Limit

Tags: c, header

I was wondering, when including header files, can the depth of include files increase without limit?  Can you specify a limit at compile time?

Example:

main.c:

```
#include "A.h"
const int xyz = CONST_VALUE;
```

A.h:

```
#include "B.h"
```

B.h:

```
#include "C.h"
```

...

...

...

Z.h:

```
#define CONST_VALUE ( 12345 )
```

Am I correct?  Can header files be included endlessly?

Comment: A related question pertaining to C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125014/are-there-limits-to-how-deep-nesting-of-header-inclusion-can-go .  One of the answers gives a quote from the C++ standard as recommending, but not necessarily requiring, support for at least 256 nested includes.  Many implementations support much deeper nesting.

Answer (score 4):

There is a limit which differs based on the compiler.

From section 6.10.2 of the [C standard])(http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *6* A `#include` preprocessing directive may appear in a source file that has been read because of a #include directive in another file, up
>   to an implementation-defined nesting limit (see 5.2.4.1).

Section 5.2.4.1:

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one
>   program that contains at least one instance of every one of the
>   following limits:
>
> ...
>
> - 15 nesting levels for #included files

So the standard states that conforming implementations must support at least 15 levels deep, but possibly more.

In practice, you probably won't hit such a limit unless you end up with a loop in your include files.

For example if you do this:

main.h:

```
#include "main.h"

extern int x;
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

int x = 2;

int main()
{
    printf("x=%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

gcc will give you the following error:

> error: #include nested too deeply

In my case (gcc 4.8.5), it went about 200 levels deep before it errored out.  See [the gcc preprocessor manual, section 11.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/cpp.pdf) for details.

For MSVC, it supports an include depth of 10 ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx)).  Note that this means (among other reasons) that MSVC is not a standard-conforming compiler.

Comment: I was wondering what effect would `#pragma once` have on preventing looping?

Comment: @ryyker Yes it will. Same as include guards (`#ifndef X #define X #endif`), as long as you put includes inside them, which you should be doing.